# How to make subtitle that not included in title block when using Madrid theme?

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{title}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
%content
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Subtitle is in the title block. I want to move the subtitle bellow the title block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could make the subtitle material part of the `author` block. If you pursue this path, be sure to (a) provide a bit of extra whitespace between the lines of the `author` block and (b) use the optional argument of `\author` to (re)state the author's real name.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{title}
%\subtitle{}
\author[name]{subtitle \\[1cm] % choose amount of vertical separation
              name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

%content
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My first slide}
fsadlkfjas
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I try using `\vspace{1cm}` that results unaligned.

Comment: @alhelal - I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. What, specifically, isn't aligned? Incidentally, my answer doesn't feature a `\vspace` instruction, does it?

Comment: don't abroad. I use this earlier but for something else that not produce expected result. Now `\vspace{1cm}` results same of yours. Thank you.

Comment: You have my upvote. Hi.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks! And, hi from Zurich, Switzerland. :-)